# Combining Java 8 and Kotlin on App Engine built with Maven

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, java-8, kotlin

I have a working multi service project on Google App Engine Standard written in Java 8. I would like to start using Kotlin in the same project too. In fact, I would like to mix Java and Kotlin in individual services/modules.

I use Maven to build and deploy. Does anybody combine this? I was looking for examples but either they use pure Kotlin or they are built with Gradle and I am not familiar with Gradle.

I do understand that I need to create a Kotlin folder aside from a Java folder in main. But not sure on the dependencies and other modifications that I need in my `pom.xml` file.

Comment: If you use Intellij, you can just create a new Kotlin file and the IDE should propose to add kotlin to your pom file. And you're done. Also you don't have to create a kotlin folder, you can put kotlin files in the same folder as your java files, which is probably cleaner.

Comment: Hmmm yes in idea but it offers converting modul into kotlin module... what is probably not the thing i want :D

Comment: I think that will just add the kotlin dependencies to your pom but can't test right now.

Comment: I am testing :) but i introduced other bug in mean time. will post result asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven project with java and kotlin is explained here:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html